# Symfony using NotEqualTo validator with an object

Tags: symfony

According to [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotEqualTo.html) it should be possible to use a NotEqualTo constraint with objects

> value
>
> type: mixed [default option]
>
> This option is required. It defines the value to compare to. It can be a string, number or **object**.

I have the following entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotEqualTo;

/**
 * Class Template
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="NoteRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="note_unique",columns={"from_id", "to_id"})})
 */
class Note
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var $id int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Template")
     * @var $from Template
     * @NotBlank()
     * @NotEqualTo(value="$to")
     */
    protected $from;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Template")
     * @NotBlank()
     * @var $to Template
     */
    protected $to;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @var $notes string
     */
    protected $notes;

    
}
```

I want to avoid getting `$from == $to`, how can I configure the constraint to use an instance of the class Template at validation time or more generrally how can I configure the constraint to use an object

Right now if a dump the values that the validator is receiving

```
class NotEqualToValidator extends AbstractComparisonValidator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function compareValues($value1, $value2)
    {
        var_dump($value1);
        var_dump($value2);
        return $value1 != $value2;
    }
}
```

I get

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Template)
string '$to' (length=3)
```

Comment: Well, your question is pretty unclear... At least for me.

Comment: I have 2 properties $from and $to of class Template, I want to avoid the user selecting the same Template instance for both properties

Comment: Oh, I get it... However, you can't to pass to value argument of NotEqualTo() any variable. Any thing passed to value argument on annotation will be a string, that is why '$to' is length 3. I think using [Constraint Targets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraint-targets) is good to go.

Comment: I'll try write a answer, I hope help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, despite Symfony docs states to be possible pass object to `NotEqualTo Constraint` it isn't true when using `YML` or `Annotations`.
So in order to dynamically unsure `Note::$to` is equals (or not equals) to `Note::$from` you could to use either [Getters Constraint Targets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraint-targets) or [Callback Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).
However, there is a third option much easier (IMO): [Expression Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html)

### Expression Constraint approach

> This constraint allows you to use an expression for more complex,
>   dynamic validation. See [Basic Usage](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html#basic-usage) for an example. See [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) for a
>   different constraint that gives you similar flexibility.

Here is an example based on your question:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/*
 * Entity class...
 */
class Note
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Template")
     * @var $from Template
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Expression('not (value == this.getTo())')
     */
    protected $from;      

    //...
}
```

That is, just add `@Assert\Expression('not (value == this.getTo())')` to `$from` property.

### Constraints Targets: Getters approach

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/*
 * Entity class...
 */
class Note
{
    //...

    /**
     * @Assert\isFalse(message='"from" cannot be equals to "to"')
     * @return bool True if self::$from is not equals to self::$to
     */
    function isFromAndToNotEqual()
    {
        return !($this->getFrom() != $this->getTo());
    }

    //...
}
```

**Setting the property path validation:**

Be aware taking this approach (*Getters As Constraints Targets*) and using validation with forms, it'll not show error messages next/closer to form field.
However, you always can set/config the [error_mapping](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#error-mapping) option (in Form type) in order to show the custom errors display next to a specific field, thus the solution would be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('from')
            ->add('to')
            // more fields...            
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            //...
            # it cause error message display next to 
            # "from" field (or whaterver field you which).
            'error_mapping' => array(
                'fromAndToNotEqual' => 'from',
            ),
        ));
    }  
}
```

---

> Please note the current solutions is based on Symfony 2.7, but it
>   should be work nicely on other older versions (except some details for
>   Form class, etc).

Comment: Thanks man that worked beautifully one, question though, in the second case is it possible to show the error message next to a field as opposed to showing a global error message?, I don't need to do this, the expression validator works just fine, I just wanted to know just in case some day I can't use the first option.

Comment: @Cesar, Absolutely! You can. But you must to set manually via error_mapping option. Please see my edited answer. Thus tell me if it work.

Comment: You're welcome! Actually your question is quite good. I'm sure it help many devs on future. ;)